# iPhone CoreData : Displaying and saving Dates

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsdate

I have some real issues with display and saving a date.  Its setup in coredata as a NSData.

I use the following to display the date but fails (datestring is returned as nil).  If I make a new date (e.g not from coredata) then its fine.

```
NSDate *date = (NSDate *) [[selectedObject valueForKey:@"timeStamp"] description];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yy"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
```

To save it I was trying to use

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yy"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];
[selectedObject setValue:date forKey:@"timeStamp"];
```

Is there something special about dates stored in coredata?

Comment: `description` method returns NSString, not NSDate, and you cannot cast one to the other. Why don't you save NSDate as date? Core Data explicitly supports dates.

Comment: Why are trying to store the dates as `NSData` or is that a Typo?

Comment: what's the result of `[date description]`? is it the date you expect?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using managedObject instead of a class for my coreData : Sorry